# How to solve $1-\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i=a_nx_n^{1/n}$ given $a_n$

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms, systems-of-equations, numerical-linear-algebra, nonlinear-system

I'm trying to solve (numerically) the following system of coupled equations:

$$1-\sum_{i=1}^Nx_i=a_nx_n^{1/n}$$ given $a_n$, I need to find the $N$ $x_n$.

I tried to write it as a matrix equation but of course, I can't isolate the vector $x$ because of the powers $1/n$.

So, is there an algorithm which would permit to solve it? Or can we isolate all the $x_n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $y = 1-\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{N}x_i$. Then, your system of equations becomes $y = a_nx_n^{1/n}$, i.e. $x_n = \left(\dfrac{y}{a_n}\right)^n$ for $n = 1,\ldots,N$.

Substituting this back into the first equation for $y$ gives us $y = 1-\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{N}\left(\dfrac{y}{a_i}\right)^i$.

Now, simply find the roots of this polynomial. Note, if all your $a_n$'s are positive, and your $x_n$'s are real, then we only care about roots $y \in (0,1)$.

Comment: But you have $y_n$ not only $y$, so:

$y_n = 1-\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{N}\left(\dfrac{y_i}{a_i}\right)^i$

for all $n$ and then this is not so simple? Well, it's a system of coupled polynomials but for $N>10$ I guess it would take too long to solve?

Comment: Wait, is your system of equations $1-\sum_{i = 1}^{N}x_i = a_nx_n^{1/n}$ for all $n = 1,\ldots,N$ or only for one value of $n$?

Comment: Oh, my bad, I've N equations..... One for each $x_n$.

Comment: But I got an idea thanks to your post, I think $y_1=y_2=y_3=y_4=\dots$ because of $y_n = 1-\displaystyle\sum_{i = 1}^{N}\left(\dfrac{y_i}{a_i}\right)^i$. So I guess i can reduce it to a single polynomial

Comment: Ok, so you have $1-(x_1+\cdots+x_N) = a_1x_1$, $1-(x_1+\cdots+x_N) = a_2x_2^{1/2}$, ...,  $1-(x_1+\cdots+x_N) = a_Nx_N^{1/N}$, right? Then, $y = a_1x_1 = a_2x_2^{1/2} = \cdots = a_Nx_N^{1/N}$, i.e. it's the same $y$ that is equal to each of the $a_nx_n^{1/n}$ terms.

Comment: Yeah, thanks a lot!